# No follow up value in command line argument in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am using `argparse` module in my Python code for command line arguments. I have some arguments that have some follow up values, ex. `-x <value>`. I have a situation in which follow up value is not required but I am not able to understand how do I implement it in the code.
The following can be the situations:
`python abc.py -x 123 -f` or `python abc.py -x 123`
`-f` is not compulsory but if it is given, no follow up value is required.

Comment: I think you are talking about a flag correct? In that case you can do something like this: `your_parser_object.add_argument('-f', action='store_true')` (you can also set `store_false` for the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `action="store_true"` in `add_argument`. This makes the argument take no follow up value and if it is present then it stores true for what ever variable you specify in `dest` variable of `add_argument`.
See [argparse store options.](http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/#argument-actions)